# Creating a standardized data table entry from multiple different formats

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains a number of fields. One of these fields is "Sample" and due to a variety of inputs my samples are named using a variety of formats. Here are some examples:

```
 "12" "250" "1248" "1_100111" "16_100111" "125_081811" "1249_100111"
```

The above examples represent the majority of the samples. I would like to change all of the samples to a 4 digit format so they can be easily sorted. The final result of the above examples would be:

```
 "0012" "0250" "1248" "0001" "0016" "0125" "1249"
```

Thus, in some cases zeros must be added and in other cases, the date marker must be cut off.
It is very important that the changes are made within the context of a data frame and returned in the same format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
x <- c("12", "250", "1248", "1_100111", "16_100111", "125_081811", "1249_100111")
sprintf(as.numeric(gsub("(\\d*)_*\\d*$", "\\1", x)), fmt="%04d")

[1] "0012" "0250" "1248" "0001" "0016" "0125" "1249"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sprintf("%04s",
  sub("_.+", "", c("12", "250", "1248", "1_100111", "16_100111", 
                   "125_081811", "1249_100111" ) )
[1] "0012" "0250" "1248" "0001" "0016" "0125" "1249"
```

Comment: +1 Snap. What do I win? Answered at exactly the same instant.

Comment: I thought about the `sub` vs. `gsub` issue and decided to go with the one that was more "ruthless" in removing everything after the first "_". Your code would only remove second underscores if there were two separated by a character. I also think mine is more economical in that it does not convert to a numeric intermediate.

Comment: Your solution is much better, no doubt about that.

Comment: Nice use of that new IronicModern typeface.

Comment: This seems to be a really elegant solution but when i try to run it on my data frame it doesnt seem to work properly. I've simply substituted the name of the data frame in for the data entry. Can you help?

Comment: @Dwin The data frame that Im using looks like the one I used in this earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641666/changing-text-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: You should have subsitituted either dfrmname$colname or dfrmname[["colname"]]